# Getting photos by State (location) using Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is it possible to use the Facebook API to return all photos taken within a country's state?

Facebook already does something similar:

facebook.com/search/**ID-OF-STATE**/photos-in/no-reshares/me/friends/photos-2/intersect

E.G

https://www.facebook.com/search/112841558741846/photos-in/no-reshares/me/friends/photos-2/intersect

Answer (score 0):

for users of your app or their friends (depending on the permissions you ask), you can use FQL

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post

Try following

```
select post_id from locaiton_post where author_uid=(select uid from <>) and type="photo"
```

Comment: Tried that, but I need all the photos (including those created or tagged with the user and all the user's friends) that are limited solely by the fact that they're from a specific state (e.g. NSW, Australia) like the link.

Comment: Yes- You need do above. You would need to define longitude and latitude boundaries for state (I think this should be available online somewhere". I looked at FB APIs, they offer places w.r.t longitude and latitude only.

Comment: With the method provided, it would only return photos which the user's friends have published themselves.

Searching through location_post with lat/lon requires distance. Since some regions have distances which are greater than FB's allowed limit (500km), this method of searching doesn't work well with states that are fairly large.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried doing the same thing and I dont think its possible at the moment.

The location_post Thoughtful Monkey references wont work since its limited to posts where:

- you were tagged in the Post
- a friend was tagged in the Post
- you authored the Post
- a friend authored the Post

According to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post

Ive searched high and low for it, but cant find a way. It looks like facebooks "photos-in" query is restricted for facebook use at the moment.